# How to run jmeter samplers for specific throughput

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to load test my application.I have a sampler under Transaction Controller.But we have updated some of the parameters in the request.So i want to run 90% time old sampler and 10% of time new sampler,which are almost doing same thing but only have some extra parameters in second sampler.I tried checking switch controller but could not figure out if it will work for my requirements.My test plan looks similar to this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with the Switch Controller you can proceed with the following "Switch Value" (or equivalent)

```
${__javaScript( var s="000000000001"; s.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*s.length) ))}
```

Another options are in (you may find them easier to implement):

- [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
- [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/)

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)